# Android Java - get place name from json object response

Tags: android, json, api, android-volley, geocode

how to get value "A Salam St, Sib, Oman" in string placename in android application. json response attached as image . please check
{

```
String URL="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng="+myLat+","+myLong+"&&key=XXX";
                RequestQueue requestQueue= Volley.newRequestQueue(MercahntUpdate.this);
                //etMID.setText("");
                JsonObjectRequest objectRequest=new JsonObjectRequest(
                        Request.Method.GET, URL, null,
                        new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                                Log.e("success",response.toString());
                                    String loudScreaming = response.optJSONArray("results[0].address_components.formatted_address").toString();

                            }
                        },
                        new Response.ErrorListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                                Log.e("error",error.toString());


                            }
                        }
                );
```

[image]

Comment: First get a `JSONArray` from `response` using key `"results"`. Then get the `JSONObject` from the 0 index of that array. Then access the `String` required from the `JSONObject` using key `"formatted_address"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drop the raw Json into http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ and create a class to handle serialization. Then you would be able to access the `formatted_address` from a getter.

the below PSEUDO code would go into your `onResponse`

```
for(Result res : response.results){
res.getFormattedAddress();
}
```

Comment: there is no other way to get details directly ?